# Displaytag format tag currency

Tags: java, jsp, format, locale, displaytag

Im using displaytag 1.2 and fmt tags:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
```

Im trying to use displaytags format-attribute to format a number to a currency. However it seems as displaytag renders the currency-format different than fmt-numberformat. This causes inconsistens in my page and needs to be resolved. 
Ex. Displaytag formats local currency like this: NOK 1,500.00
Ex. FMT formats local currency like this: kr 1 500,00

The FMT version is correct, so i would like to use the same format in displaytag. 
How can i get displaytag to format in the correct way?

Preferably without decorators.

This is my current jsp-code snippets:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency"><s:property value="reportFooter.pris" /></fmt:formatNumber>
<display:column property="pris" sortable="true" titleKey="report.header.price" format="kr {0,number,currency}"/>
```

Comment: where did you tried that.. , what Java API??

Comment: I just added some more information about it. Look at the taglibs at the top to see what libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cheap test:

```
int i = 1000;
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat("{0,number,currency}", new Locale("no", "NO"));
System.out.println(mf.format(new Object[] {new Integer(i)}));
```

Prints out `kr 1 000,00`

```
int i = 1000;
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat("{0,number,currency}", new Locale("en", "NO"));
System.out.println(mf.format(new Object[] {new Integer(i)}));
```

Prints out `NOK1,000.00`

Your problem is that you did not configure displaytag's LocaleResolver correctly. It has Norway locale but with English language.

Displaytag's code is fine, it does exactly the same as I do in my test code:

```
50  public MessageFormatColumnDecorator(String pattern, Locale locale)
51  {
52      this.format = new MessageFormat(pattern, locale);
53  }

58  public Object decorate(Object columnValue, PageContext pageContext, MediaTypeEnum media)
59  {
60      try
61      {
62          return this.format.format(new Object[]{columnValue});
63      }
64      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! But how do i configure the displaytags LocalResolver to have Norwegian language?

Comment: Since you rely on JSP and FMT, have a look at [this](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/i18n.html). Read the section 'Locale resolution' and use the `I18nJstlAdapter`.